# How do I ask about a (math) test results in Spanish?

Tags: gramática, matemáticas

I want to ask someone how someone's maths exam results went, how would I say it?

How accurate is: `¿Cómo fueron sus resultados de matemáticas?`

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities here. If you're adressing a teacher, boss, etc. (which is a case I don't think probable here), your suggestion would be pretty accurate (even though I would say *¿Cómo fue el resultado de su examen [de matemáticas]?*).
If you're adressing a friend or a colleague, which is the most common case, you can say *¿Qué tal el examen de matemáticas?* (in which *resultados* is implied), or *¿Cómo te fue en el examen de matemáticas?*, or (if you want to be more direct) *¿Qué tal la/cuál fue tu nota en el examen de matemáticas?*
Hope this helps, and please don't hesitate if you need further clarifications

Comment: I like "¿Cómo te fue en el examen de matemáticas?" best.